# Can mutation rate be selected for?

Tags: evolution, mutations, natural-selection

Can the mutability of DNA be selected for in a population? I don’t mean selection for the phenotype that is the result of a mutation. Rather, can the rate of mutations in a population be increased by natural selection?

Comment: You might be interested in [this question and answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/65262/do-organisms-have-a-mechanism-to-control-how-fast-mutations-occur/65268#65268).

Comment: The short answer is `yes`. There is quite a bit of work, theory and empirical on the evolution of mutation rate. To nicely answer, one would need to make a good review, probably inspired by some existing review. Such answer would take some time but I think is worth it.

Comment: You may like [this reference](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022283612008182?via%3Dihub). It clearly makes the case for the selection of an "ideal" mutation rate in the HIV virus.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

> Evolutionary success of bacteria relies on the constant fine-tuning of
>   their mutation rates, which optimizes their adaptability to constantly
>   changing environmental conditions. When adaptation is limited by the
>   mutation supply rate, under some conditions, natural selection favours
>   increased mutation rates by acting on allelic variation of the genetic
>   systems that control fidelity of DNA replication and repair. Mutator
>   alleles are carried to high frequency through hitchhiking with the
>   adaptive mutations they generate. However, when fitness gain no longer
>   counterbalances the fitness loss due to continuous generation of
>   deleterious mutations, natural selection favours reduction of mutation
>   rates. Selection and counter-selection of high mutation rates depends
>   on many factors: the number of mutations required for adaptation, the
>   strength of mutator alleles, bacterial population size, competition
>   with other strains, migration, and spatial and temporal environmental
>   heterogeneity. Such modulations of mutation rates may also play a role
>   in the evolution of antibiotic resistance.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16677295

---

Large differences in mutation rates can be found among viruses: 10^-3 mutations per nucleotide per replication in RNA bacteriophage Qβ versus 10^-8 mutations per nucleotide per replication in DNA Herpes simplex virus. Generally, RNA viruses have higher mutation rate because RNA-dependent RNA polymerases lack the proof-reading capacity present in DNA polymerases. However, both increasing and decreasing these typical mutation rates leads to reduced virulence of the virus population.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16220146

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16327776

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes and your nice question was answered several decades ago by Luria and Delbruck. Take few minutes to read their experiment that gives them the Nobel prize:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luria%E2%80%93Delbr%C3%BCck_experiment

Comment: I think the OP is not asking about wether the trait "mutation rate" is affected by selection on the mutation rate and not whether mutations appear as a response to a selection pressure for a given trait. I understood the question as you did at first (and got four downvotes in a few hours!) and ended up deleting my answer.

Comment: Well partially I think that can be answered by their experiment. This because in their experiment they show that bacteria have already all the possible mutations that can be "selected" in a particular environment. The selection of a mutation can happen randomly or as evolutionary biologist think it is selected by "natural selection". But what is natural selection? Are there specific mechanisms that can explain natural selection? I think this is still an open question nowadays. Please tell me what you think am open for this discussion :)